# Error : expected a ";"

Tags: c++, declare

Well this is a silly question but I have this error :

```
#include <unordered_set> 
std::unordered_set<std::string> ValidValues **{**"one", "two", "three"};
```

Error : expected a ";" appears at the first bracket. Exacty the same with a "set".

Restarted Visual Studio 2010 and the computer.

Comment: You need to include `<string>`.

Comment: According to [this](https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport), you'll need Visual C++ 11.0 (i.e. 2012) or later to use list initialisation.

Comment: @MikeSeymour That should be an answer, methinks.

Comment: How is this *so* downvote-worthy? It's not actually a missing `;`, it's the compiler obscurely saying "I don't support this part of C++11 yet."

Comment: This isn't a bad question per se, indeed. It has all the necessary info. And the close votes are completely mad.

Comment: Thanks Angew. I expected a bit this kind of reaction ;)
BUt I cannot invent the reason
Including string didnt change anything
Mike : OK I'm gonna change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set> 
std::unordered_set<std::string> ValidValues {"one", "two", "three"};
```

with [GCC 4.4+](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), [Clang 3.1+](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html), and [MSVS2013+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).

[MSVS2010/2012 does not support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) the language feature called [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), wich is what you are doing.

Comment: Doens't compile with VS 2012

Comment: @Mr.Starck You're right, the 2012 November CTP added language support for them, but didn't modify the library to add the `std::initializer_list` constructors, and so 2013 it is.